# Como ordenar uma lista pelo código digitado, em java

Tags: java, lista

Eu queria criar um código que armazenasse um código, nome, endereço e cidade de clientes, utilizando uma lista para armazenar as informações. Utilizando o Insertion Sort.

Answer (score 0):

**1 - crie um Objeto que tem as informações**

```
 class Objeto{

        int codigo;
        String nome;
        String endereco;

        public Objeto(int codigo, String nome, String endereco) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
            this.nome = nome;
            this.endereco = endereco;
        }

        public int getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public String getEndereco() {
            return endereco;
        }
    }
```

**2-Crie e instancie um Array, logo após adicione a lista os dados que deseja**

```
List<Objeto> minhaLista = new LinkedList<>(); //instaciando
    minhaLista.add(new Objeto(codigo, nome, endeco));//adicionando o elemento
```

**3-Se quiser recuperar os dados, pode usar uma estrutura de repetição pegando os índices**

```
for(Objeto o : minhaLista){
  
int codigo = o.getCodigo;//assim se faz com o resto dos itens

}
```

Obs: Pode ser usado para instanciar sua lista, LinkedList, List, ArrayList e outros dependendo do projeto. segue a documentação :
[Documentão LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)